# Get multiple selected text options with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, drop-down-menu

How to have a hyphen between two values?
This is my code:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
          
        $('input').val('default');   
       $('select').change(function() {
  var var_id = $(':selected').text();
     
     
         $('input').val(var_id);
                
            
         });
          
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
 <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
  <option value="C">C</option>
 <option value="D">D</option>
</select>

<select>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>

<input type="text" value="">
```

This is the result I received:

[image]

This is what I want:

[image]

How to have a hyphen between two values?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would modify your code, it gives you the expected results regardless of the content of the selected option text:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
          
        $('input').val('default');   
        $('select').change(function() {
  var var_id = [];
                $(':selected').each(function(index, item){
                      var_id.push(item.innerText)
                });
     
     
                $('input').val(var_id.join(' - '));
                
            
         });
          
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
 <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
  <option value="C">C</option>
 <option value="D">D</option>
</select>

<select>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>

<input type="text" value="">
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use "id" in html:

```
<div>
  <select id="alphabet">
    <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
  <option value="C">C</option>
    <option value="D">D</option>
</select>

<select id="id">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>

<input type="text" value="">
</div>

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

        $('input').val('default');   
        $('#id').change(function() {
        const id = $('#id :selected').text();
        const alphabet = $('#alphabet :selected').text();
        $('input').val(alphabet + "-" + id);  
         });
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('input').val('default');   
    $('select').change(function() {
        var var_id = $(':selected').text();
        $('input').val(var_id[0] + ' - ' + var_id[1]);
    });
});
```

Also, if you want to use an ES6 template literal, you can use:

```
$('input').val(`${var_id[0]} - ${var_id[1]}`);
```

Answer (score 1):

When any `select` menu changes, you could `push` each select value and `join` with the hyphen delimiter.

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {
  $('input').val('default');   
  $('select').change(function() {
    let values = [];
    $('select').each(function () {
      values.push(this.value);
    });
    $('input').val(values.join('-'))
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
 <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
  <option value="C">C</option>
 <option value="D">D</option>
</select>

<select>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>

<input type="text" value="">
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of applying `text` directly to the array of elements returned by `$(':selected')` you can map each element to their `text` representation and then join the array of the text-values:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
          
        $('input').val('default');   
        $('select').change(function() {
          var var_id = $(':selected').map(function () {
            return $(this).text()
          }).toArray().join("-");
           
          $('input').val(var_id);
       });
          
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
 <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
  <option value="C">C</option>
 <option value="D">D</option>
</select>

<select>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>

<input type="text" value="">
```